# Joining layers in an illustrator file together

Tags: adobe-illustrator

My Illustrator file contains multiple word clouds, which I have completed. I have saved these in separate files, but would also like one file with all of my art work. However, as there are many layers of text, the file is very slow. Is there a way that I can combine multiple layers to make the word clouds into separate images, which should then speed up the file?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would it be faster if they are in one object?

Answer (score 1):

The more objects you have in a single illustrator document the longer it takes to open. There is no solution to this. A bigger file takes longer to load that is just how it is.